# Salesforce Soap API Attachment FileSize

Tags: soap

Team,

We are using Salesforce Soap API to attach files to our cases. I see this is working fine for files less than 25MB. Want this to be work for files around 2GB in size. Can you please suggest options for this.

Answer (score 3):

Quote from the [Attachment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_attachment.htm) documentation:

> **The create call restricts these files to a maximum size of 25 MB**. For a file attached to a Solution, the limit is 1.5 MB. The maximum email attachment size is 3 MB.

This corresponds to the 25 MB limit for attachments in related list - See [File Size Limits in Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_files_size_limits.htm).

To go larger you would need to switch to using [Chatter files](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_collaboration_files.htm&language=en_US) (2 GB) or Content (2 GB). You will need to use the REST API to upload 2 GB files for Content.

For Content, the [Content Data Model](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_content.htm#sforce_api_erd_content) and [ContentVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm) API object will be useful starting points. [Differences between Files, Salesforce CRM Content, Salesforce Knowledge, Documents, and Attachments](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_files_differences.htm) would be helpful for making overall comparisons.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance. Is Content an equivalent API available in Salesforce for this.

Comment: Content isn't 1-to-1 equivalent to attachments. The data model is more complex, with versioning and workspaces. It is however a mechanism to store large files in Salesforce.

Comment: Looking at "File Size Limits in Salesforce" I think I need to use REST API instead of SOAP for uploading files greater than 35MB to GUS.

Comment: @user22451 Yes, for CRM Content the limit is "38 MB when uploaded via SOAP API" versus "2 GB when uploaded via REST API"

Comment: If I want to upload attachments more than 2GB to GUS.Is there any other API available to do this?

Comment: We have code already running with SOAP API. If we switch to REST I believe we need to change all the code. Is there a way to fix the attachment issue with minimal code change.

Comment: @user22451 You can continue to use the SOAP API for the majority of your code and then just use the REST API for the content upload. I've often mixed and matched between the two APIs from .NET based on the differences between them.